# React - getting "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following component:

```
const [eventCounter, setEventCounter] = useState(0)

let subsectionRefs = data ? Object.values(data).reduce((acc, event) => {
    acc[event.id] = useRef();
    return acc;
}, {}) : {};

    const setRankChangeFocus = eventID => {
    setEventCounter(eventCounter + 1);
    window.scrollTo(0, subsectionRefs[eventID].current.offsetTop);
};

return (
                    <Comp
                        key={event.id}
                        onRankChange={(value) => {
                            setRankChangeFocus(value);
                        }}
                    />
```

)

Essentially, i want `subsectionRefs` to re-initalize itself every time `setRankChangeFocus(value)` is called from the child component `Comp`.

However, i'm getting the "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" error when i load the page - why? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your `setEventCounter` function from within `setRankChangeFocus`, which is neither a custom hook nor a proper React function component. See the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't [use hooks in conditions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks) like you doing with `useRef`.

> Only call Hooks at the top level. Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

Comment: Not sure why? What condition? Without using the state hook, everything is working fine.

Comment: You using a ternary operator which is a conditional operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator, check your linter errors, you should get an error on this.

Comment: Ok but again, it is working.. it's only after I introduced the setState hook that it started giving me that error.

Comment: As for how hooks implemented, they must be called in a particular order, I guessing on adding another hook before the condition adds the error. You should make a producible example as expected if you want to get more insights, but either way, your code should be fixed as it is wrong (try adding a linter to your project).